# Disable snmpd log in BSD?

Tags: linux, logging, snmp, bsd

I can disable SNMP log using `snmpd.options` in RHEL or CentOS, but I can't find any solution in BSDs. Does anyone knows how to disable it or change the log location? 
The SNMP message is fillng up my /var directory always, and it's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the options to pass to daemons, but how you can configure it is depends on BSDs (much like it differ between Linux distributions). So, you better refer to documentation.

For FreeBSD 9.x + net-snmp installed via ports, you can configure such in `/usr/local/etc/rc.conf` as variable `snmpd_flags`. Check `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/snmpd` how it is used.